# How to transfer music from zip archive to Banshee

Tags: banshee, archive, zip

Whenever I open a 2gb zip file using Banshee, it plays fine until I close the archive, at which point it ceases to play. Why won't it play the songs when the archive is closed, just like it does for every zip or rar album I have in my "Downloads" folder?

Comment: Why on earth would you put music in a zip or rar?  It can't be compressed more.

Comment: What do you mean? I bulk downloaded all this music from my mediafire account and it automatically compressed it into a zip file. Any time I download album sized zip or rar files it works fine.

Comment: That is awfully goofy of them.  Unzip it once you've downloaded it then.

Comment: It stops playing because the songs are in a temporary folder when you open the zip in Banshee, once the zip is closed the temp folder is gone and the songs no longer "exist".

Comment: Uri, Moved all the songs from the zip archive to a new folder, which I then opened with Banshee. Kind of a no brainer, but I'm used to OSX where it automatically makes a copy for you once you unzip the file and move it into Itunes. Thanks!!!

Comment: @UriHerrera would you mind adding your comment as an answer so that it can be voted on and accepted?

Comment: @psusi because despite the gstreamer lack of support for mp4 chapter being documented as a bug since 2008, it is still not fixed and hence no gstreamer based apps support mp4 albums.

Comment: @gwaitsi, what's that got to do with the price of tea in China?  Nobody said anything about mp4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stops playing because the songs are in a temporary folder when you open the zip in Banshee, once the zip is closed the temp folder is gone and the songs no longer "exist".